# Use REST client to call multipart/form-data Rest web service

Tags: rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I have a RESTeasy-based REST web service (see below). I'm trying to use the google REST client to execute a request to test my service, but I'm unsure as to how the request should be setup.

I'm not sure how to send the `byte[]` as a param (`filedata`).
Any ideas on how to test this?

I get the following exception:

> java.io.IOException: Unable to get boundary for multipart

with

```
request:
-content-type=multipart/form-data
-form params:
test=testvalue
```

Rest method:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
public Response create(@MultipartForm FileUploadForm form) {
   System.out.println("form=" + form.getTest());
   return null;
}
```

FileUploadForm Pojo:

```
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.providers.multipart.PartType;

public class FileUploadForm {
    private byte[] filedata;
    private String test;

    public FileUploadForm() {}

    public byte[] getFileData() {
        return filedata;
    }

    @FormParam("filedata")
    @PartType("application/octet-stream")
    public void setFileData(final byte[] filedata) {
        this.filedata = filedata;
    }

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    @FormParam("test")
    @PartType("application/json")
    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You need to add this header to your request:

```
Accept-Encoding:multipart/form-data
```

usually you use Content type like this:

```
Content-Type: image/png
```

You can test it with [Postman REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?utm_source=gmail)

I've attached an image on how the form should be filled out.

[image: postman multipart/form-data]