# How to write Restfuse HttpTest with MULTIPART_FORM_DATA?

Tags: java, rest, junit

### I can not figure out, how to write the Rest Test. Please help me out.

I have a RestService:

```
@POST
@Path("/insertDataInDB")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response insertDataInDB(@FormDataParam("inputfile")
MultipartFormDataInput inputfile) {

    do Stuff
}
```

---

The Service works, i tested it with Chromes Rest Console.

Request URI:

```
http://localhost:8080/persDB/rest/r/insertDataInDB
```

Content Type:

```
multipart/form-data
```

Attachements Files:

```
Test.xlsx
```

Parameter Key:

```
inputfile
```

---

**How does the Rest Test look?** I tried this 
*But i can't quite figure it out, where to put the parameter key etc.*

```
@HttpTest(method = Method.POST, path = "persDB/rest/r/insertDataInDB", content = "{}", type = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, file = "inputfile.xlsx")
public void insertDataInDB() { 
  do Stuff
}
```

and i'm getting a java.io.IOException:

```
2014-02-04 16:01:30,825   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2] SEVERE org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher - Failed executing POST r/insertDataInDB: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ReaderException: java.io.IOException: Unable to get boundary for multipart
```

Comment: Unable to test with @HttpTest,
not yet implemented

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at this answer and full explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22138725/1250805)

You need to add this header to your request:

```
 Accept-Encoding:multipart/form-data
```

Comment: "The Accept-Encoding request-header field is similar to Accept, but restricts the content-codings (section 3.5) that are acceptable in the response."
https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html
The exception is clear... "java.io.IOException: Unable to get boundary for multipart" it is because they use "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" in the request without to set the boundary param.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you set the "Content-Type = multipart/form-data" without a boundary, the server is unable to read the form data appropiately.

The rest server expects something like this:
Content-Type = multipart/form-data; boundary=MY_CUSTOM_BOUNDARY

or

Content-Type = multipart/form-data; boundary=-----------------------------28947758029299

If you want to know more about the boundary you can see this link: [[What is the boundary in multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data][1])